# Loading different parts of a web page

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a webpage with a lot of youtube and soundcloud music to listen to and I was wondering what the best way would be to make it so that the music portions would not reload when certain things where clicked i.e. logging in.

Refreshing the page would start the music over again.

Ideally I would like the page to be able to play a song that would say store a small thumbnail in the corner and then the user could navigate the page freely with it still running. Kind of like how the youtube app works or, http://hypem.com

I saw someone write this bit of code, which seems pretty interesting:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="projects">
<? $page = file_get_contents("projects.html"); echo $page; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how it all works or if it is what I want so can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: I read your question over and over again, but it's a bit unclear what you want to do? Please summarize it in a clear phrase...

Comment: You've tagged this `ajax`, so it looks like you already know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you posted will not do what you want. That will load "projects.html" and render it server-side; it will cause a full page refresh when viewed. It's not even very good code.

You basically have two options, and you've already listed one of them: Frames or ajax. Frames are the old school way of doing it and generally isn't recommended. So I recommend to go read some tutorials on Ajax/XHR to familiarize yourself with it, and then you should be able to figure out how to load chunks of content onto your page without causing a full page refresh.

Comment: Do you think it will work even if the user reloads the page by Browser Refresh? I mean, isn't it something different than clicking a link on the page?

Comment: @AwalGarg No. If they hit their browser refresh button, it will refresh the whole page. Try it on Soundcloud or Songza; there's no way around this.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I was under the impression that the OP might be asking for this which is certainly not possible. Then when he pointed to that example site, I got the point. +1 for a nice answer :)